# Need to check php code

Tags: php, mysql

Use my blog.
i have this code:

[image]

how can I check ip and show the right message ?

blog pic: (need like on the photo)

[image]

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pid,ipaddress,
                            CASE 
                            when count(*) = 2 then 'ip repeated 2 times'
                            when count(*) = 3 then 'ip repeated 3 times' 
                            when count(*) > 3 then 'ip repeated more than 3 times'
                            else 'your ip is unique'
                            end as message
                            FROM posts
                            GROUP BY pid,ipaddress", $conn);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$blog['User']['ipaddress']; // user ip 
echo ??? // how can I check ip and show right message ?
```

Comment: Not readable- please post the code to your post

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, use `PDO` or `mysqli` library

Comment: @OTARIKI I don't know how :(

Answer (score 1):

Technically you just need to add `"WHERE ipadress = ".$blog['User']['ipaddress'];` to your query string.

But it is strongly recommended to avoid using mysql calls.

Try use mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
$query = "SELECT pid,ipaddress,
CASE 
WHEN count(*) = 2 THEN 'ip repeated 2 times'
WHEN count(*) = 3 THEN 'ip repeated 3 times' 
WHEN count(*) > 3 THEN 'ip repeated more than 3 times'
ELSE 'your ip is unique'
END as message
FROM posts
GROUP BY pid,ipaddress
WHERE ipaddress= ? ";
if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $blog['User']['ipaddress']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    $pid = '';
    $ipAdress = '';
    $message = '';
    $stmt->bind_result($pid, $ipAdress, $message);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo("pid = ".$pid." ; ipAdress = ".$ipAdress." ; Message = ".$message." \n");
    }
     $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: you can start just by adding `WHERE` to your query . :-)

Comment: page not working.  sorry, for strange question - can you help me if i get you ftp access ? ))) if not - all ok )

Comment: have no time now, sorry, just update your code in your post, somebody will help you for sure

Comment: i think need to add $ to mysqli->close(); in last string ?

Comment: and another error - $stmt->bind_result($pid, $ipAdress), $message;                  i edit like this $stmt->bind_result($pid, $ipAdress, $message);

Comment: just ask your question, you can use Russian to communicate if it is easier for you :-)